# Entity Framework 4 Navigation property null value throws an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, repository

I am trying to setup editing functionality using MVC3 and entity framework 4. I have a navigation property adding to my customer entity to allow me to access a one to many related entity. I have the related entity defined as virtual - its the Customer property in the below CustomerSite entity

```
namespace CustomerOrders.Domain.Entities
{
public class CustomerSite
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int CustomerSiteId { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [DisplayName("Customer Id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a unit no/street name")]
    [DisplayName("Address Line 1")]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
}
```

When i try to save an edit to the CustomerSite entity i get the following exception

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Now when i inspect the model values, the only null value is the Customer navigation property so i assuming thats whats throwing the error? EF must automatically Populate the foreign key property as the customer id field is correctly populated when i inspect the model. Thats the field i was ecpecting to be a null as i havent done anyhting extra to insert the customer ID which i am not rendering an editor for in the view.

This is my save method

```
  public void SaveCustomerSite(CustomerSite customerSite)
    {
        if (customerSite.CustomerSiteId == 0)
        {
            context.CustomerSites.Add(customerSite);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

And this is how i have the relationship defined in the EF data context

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerSite>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Customer);
    }
```

Does anyone know if the navigation property being null at the time the edit is saved will be what is causing the excpetion and if so how can i resolve this?

All advice is appreciated.

EDIT================

This is the stack trace from the exception

```
at CustomerOrders.WebUI.Controllers.SiteAdminController.Edit(CustomerSite  customerSite) in C:\Users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects \CustomerOrders\CustomerOrders.WebUI\Controllers\SiteAdminController.cs:line 43
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[]   parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext  controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15. <InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: What is the `StackTrace` for the exception?

Comment: @Craig Stuntz, Ive updated the question with the stack trace, thanks.

Comment: OK. That says the bug is in your `SiteAdminController.Edit` method, which you don't show. It seems to have never gotten as far as the actual `SaveChanges()` or `SaveCustomerSite()`, according to the trace you posted.

Comment: Hi i have resolved this now, the execption was due to me trying to use a property from the Customer entity to provide feedback after the edit has been saved. I.E, customerSite.Customer.CustomerName, thanks for taking the time to look at thus for me Craig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if (customerSite.CustomerSiteId == 0)
```

If customerSite is null when it's passed in, you cannot reference any properties.

Test for null before this line.

Answer (score 0):

An additional note.

In a master-detail setup (one-to-many) I had an issue where the detail portion was throwing an exception when only the master was being populated.  In my controller I added a check on the master-detail for if it was null.

```
if(salesMain.SalesSub != null)
{
   //do something with SalesSub
}
```